# Why is this code hanging when I execute it?

Tags: haskell

### What I'm trying to achieve

As an exercise, I'm trying to write a 'mergeSorted' function which takes two lists, and returns a single list, in which all the elements from the two lists are sorted.

For example:

- `mergeSorted [2,6,5] [3,4,1]` should return `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`
- `mergeSorted [] [4,1]` should return `[4,1]`

### Here's what I wrote:

```hs
qsort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
qsort [] = []
qsort (x:xs) = qsort smaller ++ [x] ++ qsort larger
  where
    smaller = [a | a <- xs, a <= x]
    larger = [b | b <- xs, b > x]

mergeSorted :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
mergeSorted listX [] = qsort listX
mergeSorted [] listY = qsort listY
mergeSorted listX listY   | x <= y      = x : mergeSorted xs (y:ys)
                          | otherwise   = y : mergeSorted (x:xs) ys
                          where
                            (y:ys) = sortedYs
                            (x:xs) = sortedXs
                            sortedYs = qsort ys
                            sortedXs = qsort xs
```

### The issue

The `qsort` code seems to be working well. But my `mergeSorted` isn't working.
If I execute `mergeSorted` with two lists which are not empty in GHCi, execution hangs forever. (i.e. I never get a result).

### My question

Please can you tell me what's wrong with my `mergeSorted` code?

Comment: `(y:ys) = sortedYs`, and `sortedYs = qsort ys`, hence you sort the result of the sort, and thus get stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: You’re using `qsort` a lot. Try writing a function (I’d call it `mergeSorted`, actually…) that merges two *already sorted* lists, without using `qsort` at all. (If you wanted to merge two unsorted lists into a sorted one while relying on `qsort`, it may as well be `qsort (listX ++ listY)`.)

Comment: Please be aware that your `mergeSorted` function currently does not implement anything close to the "merge sort" algorithm. You should double check your exercise and see if maybe that was the intention.

Comment: The point of merge sort is that you recursively sort each half using merge sort itself, not another sorting algorithm. Eventually, the argument to the sort becomes short enough (empty or a singleton) that it is vacuously sorted. All the "work" is done by the actual merge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You write `(y:ys) = sortedYs`, and `sortedYs = qsort ys`, hence you sort the result of the sort, and thus get stuck in an infinite loop. But even if you manage to solve that, it would not be very efficient, since for each item, you will sort the list of remaining items again.

I think it is better to simplify this in a helper function for merging, and another one that calls `qsort` (or something else) as pre-processing step:

```
import Data.Function(on)

merge :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge [] ys = ys
merge xs [] = xs
merge xa@(x:xs) ya@(y:ys)
    | x <= y = x : merge xs ya
    | otherwise = y : merge xa ys

mergeSorted :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
mergeSorted = merge `on` qsort
```